# Fatal error fetching Entity with NSSet using FetchedResultController

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have 2 Entities in my Project:

```
Product: NSObject {
    @NSManaged public var title: String?
}

ShoppingCart: NSObject {
    @NSManaged public var products: NSSet?
}
```

I want to subscribe to ShoppingCart updates on one of my ViewControllers and update the tableView inside.

I found the solution that I can do it by using NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, but while configuring it I'm getting fatal error **"to-many key not allowed here"**

```
if fetchedResultsController == nil {
            let request = NSFetchRequest<ShoppingCart>(entityName: "ShoppingCart")
            let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "products", ascending: false)
            request.sortDescriptors = [sort]
            
            fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: CoreDataService.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
            fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
        }
        
        do {
            try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
            tableView.reloadData()
        } catch {
            print("failed fetch")
}
```

I'm stuck on this task like 3 days or so, give me a hand please

Comment: Does it work without the sort descriptor? It looks like the problem is there: You ask Core Data to sort your shopping carts by its products. Products are sets, and how do you sort a number of sets? What exactly do you want to achieve with your sort descriptor?

Comment: @lazarevzubov fatal error: An instance of NSFetchedResultsController requires a fetch request with sort descriptors"

Comment: I don't think it's true. If you don't specify `sortDescriptors` you'll just get your objects unsorted. Have you tried to run your code without this line `request.sortDescriptors = [sort]`?

Comment: @lazarevzubov NSFetchedResultsController must have at least one sort descriptor, it clearly says so in the documentation. OP, I am not sure you can sort a NSFetchedResultsController on a relationship, don't you have any sortable properties in ShoppingCart?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yeah, OK, I was wrong, sorry. `NSFetchRequest` docs misled me. But my main point still seems valid – the problem is in `NSSortDescriptor`.